# Quite specific dataframe querying

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
#=================================================================================
# Building the dataframe (No Problems Here)
#=================================================================================  
plhIndex = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fullPath', 'folderName', 'fileName', 'modifiedDate'])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(processHistoryPath):
    for file in files:
        plhIndex = plhIndex.append({'fullPath' : os.path.join(root, file), \
                                    'folderName' : os.path.basename(root), \
                                    'fileName' : file, \
                                    'modifiedDate' : os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, file))}, ignore_index=True)
```

What I need is a function to return the 'fullPath' and 'folderName' from plhIndex where:

A) The fileName matches a variable i provide

B) modifiedDate is CLOSEST to a date I provide the function(both in timestamp format)

something like:
return min(plhIndex , key=lambda x:abs(date-modifiedDateColumn))
but where the serial number matches

The help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
def get_closest(fn, date, df):
    d = pd.DataFrame({'fileName': [fn], 'modifiedDate': [date]})
    a = pd.merge_asof(d, df, on='modifiedDate', by='fileName', direction='nearest')
    return a.loc[0, ['fullPath', 'folderName']].to_dict()
```

Call it like this:

```
get_closest('myfilename', some_date, plhIndex)
```

Comment: forgive me but i am not an expert in python. It looks like this function returns a dictionary? How would I extract the two bits of information I will need? ex. fullPath =       folderName=    )

Comment: You asked for two pieces of information, `'fullPath'` and `'folderName'`.  I gave you a function that returns a dictionary that has two keys, `'fullPath'` and `'folderName'`.  you can get at it with `result = get_closest('myfilename', some_date, plhIndex); result['fullPath']`

Comment: Thank You. I now realize i do not need the function to return the foldername. It works great but i have added another request for optimization on here. If you are willing, I would love your input! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371800/python-file-retrieval-optimization